# Suppress output of gc()

Tags: r, garbage-collection

Is there a possibility to suppress all messages of gc( ) in R?

The usual like `suppressWarnings(gc( ))` or `suppressMessages(gc( ))` don't work. `gc( )` itself has a `verbose` option but this is not working how I like it:

```
> gc(verbose=TRUE)
Garbage collection 375 = 234+40+101 (level 2) ... 
17.9 Mbytes of cons cells used (41%)
171.2 Mbytes of vectors used (43%)
used  (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells   334493  17.9     818163  43.7   818163  43.7
Vcells 22431904 171.2   52178020 398.1 50193465 383.0
> gc(verbose=FALSE)
used  (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells   334496  17.9     818163  43.7   818163  43.7
Vcells 22431916 171.2   52178020 398.1 50193465 383.0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems a little odd, as the only usual reason to call `gc` is to see that output.  As Hadley writes, "there's never any point in calling gc() yourself, apart to see how much memory is in use. R will automatically call run garbage collection whenever it needs more space." See http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html

Comment: @Aaron: As continued in `?gc`: "_However, it can be useful to call gc after a large object has been removed, as this may prompt R to return memory to the operating system._" In particular, I use it when I'm a) timing functions to compare speed and b) when using `read.xlsx` for larger spreadsheets--I've run into problems of memory overflows without `gc()` after reading in such objects.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I sometimes use `invisible(gc())`.

Comment: Much better than my "not pretty" approach.  Could always wrap it, i.e. `mygc <-function(...) invisible(gc(...))`

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty, but

```
foo <- gc();rm foo
```

will take care of it